# How to hide a link from a child window

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a mypage1.aspx, it has a link that opens a pop up, this pop up has another link that opens a second pop up and closes the first pop up. On the second pop up that was opened there is like a wizard, at the end there is an input and i have a function to close the window as follows (in Clients.js)

```
Clients.prototype.closeThisWindow = function() {
    window.close();
}
```

When the button is clicked the window perfectly. But now i have an issue from this same function i need to hide a link in the parent page but

```
window.parent   (parent is always null)
window.opener   (opener is always null too)
```

I have defined a function in the parent to hide the link, but can't call that function because opener is always null

i tried

```
Clients.prototype.closeThisWindow = function() {
    window.opener.hideLink();
    window.close();
}
```

Where hideLink is the function defined in the parent page, but opener is always null, is there any other way i could do this?. I am not good with javascript but here where I work they have designed it like this and i have to make it work from the javascript. I would appreciate any help given this scenario.

Comment: `hideLink` is declared on the first opened window or the "main" window?("main" -> "first opened window" -> "wizard window")

Comment: On the main window - somehow i need to be able to reference from the third level window (wizard pop up)

Comment: Pass a reference to it when opening the "wizard window" from the "first opened window", like `result_from_open.main_window = window.opener;` and change `window.opener.hideLink();` to `window.main_window.hideLink();`.

Comment: please excuse i am not too good with javascript...here is my question.. So I could literally just use it the way you typed it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function opening the wizard do:

```
var result_from_open = open(/*your paramenters*/);
result_from_open.main_window = window.opener;
```

And in Clients.js:

```
Clients.prototype.closeThisWindow = function() {
  //window.opener.hideLink();
  window.main_window.hideLink();
  window.close();
}
```